# locate-this v. identify-this vs. where-on-earth

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

How do these 3 tags differ?

There are [15 questions tagged with the first two](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locate-this+identify-this), among which two are mine. Note that I initially tagged mine just `identify-this`; someone else added the `locate-this`.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried clicking the tags? The wikis seem to answer your question perfectly clearly

> **[locate-this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locate-this)**: You know the name of a cafe, a church, etc. but you don't know where it is. Help!
>
> **[identify-this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this)**: Finding the name of some place, food, monument, or other travel-related thing.
>
> **[where-on-earth](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/where-on-earth)**: For questions about location of specific place or location of longest/highest/biggest/the most... place/thing on Earth